# Flutter web cannot access data when hosted on firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

Code that access data, works locally, when I start the app with `flutter run --release` or with `dhttpd --path build/web/`, but does not work when hosted with Firebase, deployed with command `firebase deploy`.

Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
...
final json = (await _firestore.collection(name).doc(id).get()).data();
```

Error:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#get on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore)
```

What can be missing?

Filed issue: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11354

[image]

Comment: Not sure if that's related but [MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#setData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore))](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/1903#issuecomment-586986578) says *Are you trying to use the plugin in Flutter for web? This is currently not supported.*

Answer (score 1):

I switched flutter to the stable channel and it solved the issue.